# Getting file data to put into a 2d int array?

Tags: java, applet

I want to take text file data, and put it into a 2d int[][] array. I've tried several things and all has failed. How can I do this effectively and properly?

Heres my code:

```
public void readMap() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testfile.txt"));
            String currLine;

            while((currLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(currLine);

                for(int x = 0; x < tile_nums; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < tile_nums; y++)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }   
        } 
        finally
        {
            in.close();
        }

    }
```

and my text file data:

```
100000000
111111010
100001010
111111110
000001000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
```

Comment: Your file ... doesn't contain doubles. Or anything that immediately resembles data that would go into a 2d array.

Comment: Ok, you now have a file that ... doesn't really contain ints. Or anything that immediately resembles data that would go into a 2d array.

Comment: Is each character of each line an int to go into your array? So the possible range of values is 0-9?

Comment: Well, the file is strings, I have to convert those to ints to put into the array

Comment: Please answer this question... is each line in the file a list of single digit numbers and you need a 2-d array where the outter array is the lines and each inner array is the digits in the line?

Comment: You have not given enough details nor answered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things,

First, in order to determine the size of the outter array you will need to determine the number of lines in the file. Or you can process each line to produce the inner arrays, store them in a List and create the outter array from the list.

Second, you need to take each line, determine the length (`line.length()`) to create the inner array of the appropriate size (`int[] inner = new int[line.length()];`)

Finally, convert the line to an array of `chars` and convert each `char` to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt`

I am not posting the entire solution since I think this is probably homework.